# How does MongoDB evaluates multiple $or statements?

Tags: mongodb

How will MongoDB evaluate this query:

```
db.testCol.find(
{
    "$or" : [ {a:1, b:12}, {b:9, c:15}, {c:10, d:"foo"} ]
});
```

When scanning values in a document if first OR statement is TRUE will the other statements be also be evaluated?

Logically if the MongoDB is optimized other values in OR statement should not be evaluated, but I don't know how MongoDB is implemented.

UPDATE:
I updated my query because it was wrong and it didn't explain correctly what I was trying to accomplish. I need to find a set of documents that have different properties and if an **exact** combination of these properties is found the document must be returned.

The SQL equivalent of my query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM testCol 
WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 12) OR (b = 9 AND c = 15) OR (c = 10 AND d = 'foo');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB will execute each clause of the $or operation as a seperate query and remove duplicates as a post processing pass. As such each clause can use a seperate index which is often very useful.

In other words, it will NOT look at 1 document, see which of the OR clauses apply and do an early-out if the first clause is a match. Rather it does a full dataset query per clause and de-dupe after the fact. This may seem less than efficient but in practice it's almost always faster since the first approach would only be able to hit at most one index for all clauses which is rarely efficient.

Comment: Basically if I'm using $or to search on non indexed fields, query will be slow because it will do full table scan for each statement (if I understand you correctly)?

Comment: Yes, but a query that does a full table scan will be slow regardless. In the case of $or it will be incrementally slow as you add more clauses. In practice nobody would do unindexed queries on "big data" databases though.

Comment: I see two different results in nscanned when I do an explain simply by changing the order of the items in the $or statement. This query is stupid as it by definition would include the results of the first in the query, but it indicates that mongo doesn't treat the two items separately in some cases:  https://gist.github.com/0c9b9b74655ddab7f820

Comment: @RemonvanVliet When you have search filter with a lot of options it's virtually impossible that all possible combination of queries hits an indexed field.

Comment: @Christian P True, although in practice most search filters will index the high cardinality fields.

Comment: @Spencer As you can see in the code there are some quick optimization paths for "silly" queries with 100% overlap. Your order changing might be hitting one of those. I see the same n-scanned in both cases though in your paste.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Mongo only skips documents during the de-duplication process, not during the table scans.

Mongo won't check documents that are already part of the result set. So if your first {a:1, b:12} returns 100% of the documents, Mongo is done.

You want to put whatever will grab the most documents as your first evaluated statement because of this. If your first item only grabs 1% of documents, the subsequent item will need to scan the other 99%.

That being said, you are using $or to look for values in a single key. I think you want to use $in for this.

See here for more:

http://books.google.com/books?id=BQS33CxGid4C&lpg=PA48&ots=PqvQJPRUoe&dq=mongo%20tips%20and%20tricks%20%22OR-query%22&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Sorry... my query was wrong and I was try to accomplish a different thing. I corrected it and added additional explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Individual $or clauses are treated as seperate querues and duplicates are ejected when the results are combined rather than the results of the first clause being actively filtered out before executing the second clause (say, through an under the hood $nin).

Comment: From Kristina Chodorow's book "50 Tips & Tricks for MongoDB Developers"

"OR-style queries are exactly the opposite of AND queries: try to put the most inclusive clauses first, as MongoDB has to keep checking documents that aren't part of the result set yet for every match."

Am I interpreting this incorrectly? It is possible that she is then referring to the de-dupe process, which wouldn't offer that much of a benefit then.

Comment: She is, since she's the one that just told me it's de-duping ;)

Comment: No problem. It's either that or that section of the book is outdated. The current implementation is certainly de-duping the result sets.